# Switched from Ubuntu problems Installing gedit on mac via macports. "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

Tags: macports, gedit

I recently switched to mac from Ubuntu and have been trying to enable my mac to do what i was able to do on my old computer. I want to install Gedit on my mac via command line, so i ran the command "sudo port install gedit." I have been able to use "sudo port.." to install other programs so i'm pretty sure its running correctly. however, when i go in the terminal and type "gedit" i get the "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:" error. Not exactly sure how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have x11 installed.  Press and hold the apple key and press spacebar to open up the spotlight search.  search for x11.  If it doesn't show up under the "Applications" heading, it's not installed.  Also, you are doing this directly on the machine, and not through SSH, right?  If it IS through ssh, make sure your client has an X server, and you used `ssh -X` to connect.

Comment: thanks, i did that and it at least opened but now its giving me the following error                                                    GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; the most common cause is a missing or misconfigured D-Bus session bus daemon. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Session D-Bus not running. Try running `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist'.)

Comment: what happened when you ran that `launchctl` command?

Comment: when i run that command i get   ... "** (gedit:246): WARNING **: Could not load theme icon gtk-home: Icon 'gtk-home' not present in theme

(gedit:246): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: void g_object_unref(gpointer): assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (gedit:246): WARNING **: Could not load theme icon system-file-manager: Icon 'system-file-manager' not present in theme."  Perhaps i can ignore this message being that gedit  seems to work fine? Nonetheless, if i could figure out a way to get rid of these error messages that would be nice...   thanks btw.

Comment: ya know, now that i think about it, i think i get something similar to that every time i run gedit.  if it works, it works.  I wouldn't worry about it.